# php, COM object's exec method shows nothing

Tags: php, com

dev environment:

- Windows server 2012
- apache2.4 + php5.6
- enable dot_net extention

Hello Everyone.
( First of all, I'm sorry for my poor English. )

I am writing a small php script. for example, When the user clicks the button, server execute c++ binary file, and returns that programs PID to user.

Because the need of the PID, I've used the COM object. My code is as belows..

```
$com = new COM('WScript.Shell');
$com->CurrentDirectory = "d:\\git\\myProject\\release\\bin\\";
$exec = $com->Exec("returnPID.exe"); // 
$pid = $exec->ProcessID;
echo $pid;
```

The returnPID.exe once executed, It shows its status on cmd window till it is terminated. 
( It is Win32 console application. )

Above code works well and users have no inconvenience.

But the problem is, when I execute the returnPID.exe through the COM object's Exec method, returnPID application doesn't show anything about its status on cmd window.

If I execute returnPID application through COM object's 'Run' method, application tells its status on cmd window properly. But as you all know, Run method doesn't return PID.

I want to know the reason why returnPID application doesn't show its status and  resolution.

Thank you for reading my question. :-)